# static vs default method - Functional interfaces

Tags: java-8, functional-programming

I am creating functional interfaces and want to reuse default methods with anonymous implementation.

```
public class JavaInterfaceTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FunctionalIntf fi = () -> {
        System.out.println("In ananymus impl, trying to call default method");
        // doInternal()
        return "Hello";

    };

    fi.doFunction(); // How this line valid ?
    fi.doInternal();

    FunctionalIntf.doSomething();

    }

}

@FunctionalInterface
interface FunctionalIntf {

String doFunction();

default void doInternal(){
    System.out.println("In doInternal");
}

static void doSomething(){
    System.out.println("In doSomething");
}

}
```

1. How fi.doFunction(); is valid, if I go thru anonymous implementation.
2. How can I re-sue default method or static method if I want from implementation?

**3. Is returning something valid/best practice in my case as I can not handle the returned value.**

Comment: You are asking three entirely different questions. Further, it seems you are asking the wrong questions, like “How fi.doFunction(); is valid”, as `fi` is a variable of an interface type and you are calling one of its defined methods on it, so why should it not be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating the anonymous class, you actually provide an implementation for your abstract method `doFunction()` from `FunctionalIntf` interface. So when you are using this line of code:

```
fi.doFunction();
```

It means that you are calling `doFunction()` method from the anonymous class. This is another example on how functional interfaces work:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I'm Runnable!");
    }
};
r.run();
```

In this case we override `run()` method from `Runnable` interface, which is also a functional interface.

You cannot provide another implementation for the static method because you cannot override a static method. Static methods are not inherited in Java at all. You can instead provide another implementation for the default method by overriding as mentioned in my above example.

Regarding the returned value, you need to define your method to return the exact value you need. There is no best practice in that.

Comment: fi.doFunction(); was not calling. (Not printing the text).

Comment: I just test it and the output is: `In ananymus impl, trying to call default method`.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement a  functional interface, you have 2 options:

1. Use lambdas, as you have
2. Use inner classes.

If you use lambdas, like you have, you have the default implementation of the static/default methods along with the implementation of the abstract method.

If you use an inner class, the normal rules of overriding applies.